# How can i set the text vertically in a side-bar in html and css

Tags: html, css, frontend

How can I set the text to appear rotated vertically and bottom aligned in my side bar. A descriptive answer will be appreciated describing where I am going wrong and please guide me to proper resources for clearing concepts as I struggle a lot with CSS.I am facing trouble in rotating text and aligning in the sidebar.

```css
/* Global Styles */

@media screen and (min-width: 320px){
    html, body{
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    body{
        background-image: url("../images/recordMobile.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }

    .sidebar{
        height: 100%;
        width: 4rem;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0.7);
        color: hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 0%;
        z-index: 1;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <title>Recor-di-ary</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Main Container -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Navigation Container -->
        <div class="nav-container">
            <nav>
                <a href="#">
                    Home
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    Studies
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    Development
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    Personal
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- End Navigation Container -->
        <!-- Document head -->
        <div class="head-container sidebar">
            <h1>Recor-di-ary</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- End Document Head -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Main Container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this - Just use rotate transform

```css
/* Global Styles */

@media screen and (min-width: 320px){
    html, body{
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    body{
        background-image: url("../images/recordMobile.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }

    .sidebar{
        height: 100%;
        width: 4rem;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0.7);
        color: hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 0%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    h1 {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <title>Recor-di-ary</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Main Container -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Navigation Container -->
        <div class="nav-container">
            <nav>
                <a href="#">
                    Home
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    Studies
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    Development
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    Personal
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- End Navigation Container -->
        <!-- Document head -->
        <div class="head-container sidebar">
            <h1>Recor-di-ary</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- End Document Head -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Main Container -->
</body>

</html>
```